# How to calculate the Poisson index of dispersion?

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics

I came across the [Poisson index of dispersion](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indice_di_dispersione_di_Poisson). I find it very interesting. But I didn't understand how to apply it.

[image]

It is simply necessary: `Standard Deviation / Mean` ?
(and then of course I insert the result in Poisson)

For example if i have:

```
mean=1.6
variance 0.25
standard deviation: 0.50
```

then the Poisson index of dispersion will be:
`0.50/1.6 = 0.3125`?

Subsequently it will be 0.3125 to be inserted into the Poisson distribution. Can you show me a practical example with numbers please?

**UPDATE**

My all steps is:

1. I have a set of: `2, 1, 1, 2, 2` and i calculate its `main` and it is `1.6`.
2. I calculate the `variance` of 1.6 and it is: `0.2592`
3. `Index_of_Dispersion = Variance / Main`, so 0.2592 / 1.6 = `0.162`
4. I use 0.162 in Poisson

Comment: `sigma^2` is the variance, not the standard deviation. If the distribution is Poisson then the variance and the mean should be equal. The more the ratio differs from `1` the less likely that the data is from a Poisson distribution.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon   Why should variance and mean be the same? If I have a set of: 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, I calculate its average and it is 1.6. Its variance will therefore be 0.25. Subsequently variance / mean = 0.15625

So will I have to put 0.15625 in the Poisson distribution? Can you explain yourself better? Thank you

Comment: @Horiatiki By definition, the variance of a Poisson distribution is Its mean:
$$ $$
`Variance[PoissonDistribution[u]]`
`(*u*)`
$$ $$
So Bob is saying that the ratio will always be 1 for a Poisson distribution.

For a list, you can calculate the ratio of variance to mean by:
$$ $$
`lst = {2, 1, 1, 2, 2};`
$$ $$
`Variance[lst]/Mean[lst]`

Comment: @ydd Could you show me a more detailed practical example please? I will be happy to vote and accept your answer. How do I divide a list (consisting of 5 numbers) by an average?

Comment: @ydd Should I just use 0.2592 / 1.6 =0.162?

Comment: The Poisson distribution only has a single parameter. The mean and variance cannot be independently set. If you set the mean, then you have also set the variance.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

d[n_Integer?Positive] := d[n] =
  Module[{data},
   SeedRandom[1234];
   data = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[1.6], n];
   Variance[data]/Mean[data]]

ListLinePlot[d /@ Ceiling[10^Range[1, 6, 1/2]],
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Log10[n]], "variance/mean"},
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10},
 DataRange -> {1, 6}]
```

[image]

As the sample size increases, the ratio converges to 1

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is not helpful to me. If by setting the mean, I also set the variance, because as the sample size increases the ratio converges to 1...then why does the Poisson Index of Dispersion exist? What is the purpose of the Poisson index of dispersion if it is useless to calculate it?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to tell me. There was no need to write an answer just to show me that as the sample size increases the ratio converges to 1. I would like an answer to the main question I asked. You said the mean and variance can't be set independently, ok, so how to solve?

Comment: As @ydd said in the comment, take the ratio Variance[list]/Mean[list]. This ratio is a measure of how well the data represents a Poisson distribution or alternatively whether the sample size is large enough to reasonably represent a Poisson distribution. This site is for Q&A about the software application Mathematica and the Wolfram language. For questions about statistics you should ask at.                                   [`Cross Validated`](https : // stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't understand what Variance[list]/Mean[list] means. Could you give me an example please considering that my list (from which I calculate the average) is 2, 1, 1, 2, 2? I look forward to your comment. Thank you

Comment: With `list = {2, 1, 1, 2, 2}` then `mean = Mean[list] // N` evaluates to `1.6` and `var = Variance[list] // N` evaluates to `0.3` The ratio `var/mean` is `0.1875` This ratio is far from `1` so the sample size is too small to be a decent representation of a Poisson distribution.

Comment: @Bon Hanlon The few values in the list are just an easy example. CURIOSITY 1: Now that I got 0.1874, will the ratio always be 1 for a Poisson distribution? CURIOSITY? 2: What is the difference in proceeding like this (and obtaining 0.1874) and in proceeding when you said that as the sample size increases the ratio converges to 1? It seems the same to me. I hope you will answer :)

Comment: The **variance and mean of a Poisson distribution are identical**. Consequently, their ratio is always `1`. The ratio for data can have any value. The closer the data is to being Poisson distributed, the closer the ratio will be to 1. For random data generated from a Poisson distribution, the larger the data set, the closer the data will be to being Poisson distributed and the closer the ratio will be to `1`. This is my last interaction on this topic.